# How to make an array of attributed text

Tags: swift

I need an array of attributed text.  I need the color of each element to change depending on its position in the array (this would be achieved through HSV, as the hue value would correlate with the position).  The array varies depending on user input, and I don't know how to write it so that it automatically changes the color.  I have the user's input split up into an array, so how would I turn each word into attributed text?  I have absolutely no idea of how to do this, so thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It would help if you could be more specific. Perhaps provide some code you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this even more concisely by using `enumerate` and `map`:

```
let strings  = ["The", "Cat", "In", "The", "Hat"]

let attribStrings = strings.enumerate().map { index, element in
    return NSAttributedString(string: element, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor(hue: CGFloat(index)/CGFloat(strings.count), saturation: 0.5, brightness: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)])
}
```

You are mapping every original element in the array to an `NSAttributedString` with the text color of `UIColor(hue: CGFloat(index)/CGFloat(strings.count), saturation: 0.5, brightness: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)`. You should adjust the saturation and brightness to your liking.

Output to a `UILabel` would look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the NSForegroundColorAttributeName to change the colour of the NSAttributedString. I have included below a sample that creates
64 different colours.

```
func colorUsingHSV( index : Int, total : Int) -> UIColor
{
    return UIColor(hue: CGFloat((CGFloat(index)/CGFloat(total))), saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
}

func generateAttributeText()
{
  var attrStrings = [NSAttributedString]()
  for i in 1...64
  {
    let attrString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Text")
    attrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: colorUsingHSV(i,total: 64), range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

    attrStrings.append(attrString)
  }
}
```